# Intellij IDEA - Method not found if return child class

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I use Intellij IDEA for php developing.

```js
class A {
}

class B extends A {

  public function myFunc() {}

}

class C {

  /**
     * Return class object
     *
     * @return A
     */
  public function get() {
    return $a_or_child_a_class_from_some_list;
  }

}

$cObject = new C();
$cObject
  ->get()
  ->myFunc();// Intellij say that method not found. How pretty resolve this problem?
```

I code above I demostrate situation when class C return object based on class A. How I can say Intellij that in this situation I use class B with ->myFunc() method. Yes, I can enumeratue in @reuturn classes but it is not solution. Also can describe $cObject->get() with B class `/*@type B*/` but it is not good.

What you can suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, clearly your class `A` doesn't define method `myFunc()`, so why would IntelliJ resolve the method name?

You should either describe the return type as `B`, define abstract method `myFunc()` in `class A` or (in my opinion the best option) define an interface with method signatures and declare the interface as a return type for your `get()` method.

**Edit:**
If you define an abstract method, then the class must also be abstract. So in your case, if you don't want to declare `A` as abstract, you could simply define a method `myFunc()` with empty body.